# angular.element().scope function not working in fb script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, api, sdk

After the response, I want to call angular function from outside js and it seems so surprise to me as this function throws an error

```
  function _i(){
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('vikas_facebook')).scope().connectWithFacebook(response);
    });
 }
```

AngularJs Function

```
$scope.connectWithFacebook = function (response) {

   // Saving response data in our database

}
```

I have used this function many times and it worked perfectly but in fb.api It throws an error. PFA regarding this[image]

Comment: Seems like a script isn't getting loaded correctly if it really does work everywhere else

Comment: Does `document.getElementById('vikas_facebook')` element exist when you are trying to get `scope`

Comment: @georgeawg Same error as above that I attached in image

Comment: Log the expression by parts to see which part is failing. Read [How to debug small programs.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: There are several possible causes of this problem. [Data Debug](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) might not be enabled. The `.scope()` method may be returning `$rootScope` instead of the desired scope. Or the code creating the scope property `connectWithFacebook` may not have been executed yet. Or the element with`ID='vikas_facebook` may not yet be instantiated. Use simple debugging techniques to eliminate possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happen in your code but your code should be work. but this type of function calling not good practice. So you can follow below link for avoid this problem too [Facebook SDK for JavaScript with AngularJS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs)

Comment: Will you know how to handle that function

Comment: which function? and also refer below example http://plnkr.co/edit/mA7dzreUlqqTJZqodAzv?p=preview